# Asymptotic probability that two integers are coprime

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

I'm having difficulty with a number-theory-type exercise. Could you provide assistance with computing the asymptotic probabilities that two integers are coprime (both integers tending to
$\infty$), given that their
maximum is even?

I have essentially no experience in number theory and have been asked this by a colleague, so I thought I'd pass it over here.

Comment: I saw a proof of this somewhere using the zeta function. I'll try and dig it up. EDIT: Here it is: http://www.mathreference.com/lc-z,cop.html.

Comment: OP: Can you prove the main ingredient the proof in the accepted answer relies on (that divisibilities by different primes are independent events)?

Comment: Yes I can prove this.

Comment: Then adding this proof would make the page much more useful to its potential readers. (Unrelated: Please use `@user` to signal a comment to `user`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two integers are coprime iff there is no prime $p$ dividing both of them, so the asymptotic probability is:
$$ \frac{1}{2}\prod_{p>2}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)=\frac{2}{3}\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)=\frac{2}{3\zeta(2)}=\color{red}{\frac{4}{\pi^2}}.$$

Comment: ...Assuming that divisibilities by different primes are independent events--which is kind of the main part of the proof.

Comment: The actual probability is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$, using Dirichlet's convolution on Euler's totient function and Möbius' function